# I want to know how is someone able to make such vertices as in this attested pic on upper-left and lower-right corners

Tags: html, css, button, tailwind-css

How to code for these kinds of buttons using only HTML & CSS?

I want to know how is someone able to make such vertices as in this attested pic on upper-left and lower-right corners.

[image]

How to code for this button design using HTML, CSS and TAILWIND CSS only?

Comment: Looks like it's using box-shadow. Why not examine the page you've used to see how they did it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use box-shadow:
like:

```css
#demo {
box-shadow: -7px 7px 0px 0px black;
background:gray;
  width:300px;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-top:10px;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">Edit this text</div>
```